# how to make a chat screen with text messages on both sides of the screen and scrollable with kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am writing a chat application in python using kivy. I am struggling to make the main part of the chat - Text messages (in the same size) on both sides of the screen that can also be scrollable, just like whatsup/telegram/normal messages chat.

I tried using the ScrollView and the RecycleView but I can't make the Labels not take all the screen width and be on diffrent sides.

```
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        #recycle view - freinds list
        RV:
            spacing: 10
            size_hint: 0.25,1
            viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
            id: chats
            SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size: None, dp(56)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: (1, 1, 1)
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    source: 'cryptychat.png'

            #this part is where the messages needs to be
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                spacing: 10
                Label:
                    text: "testing"
                    text_size: self.size
                    size_hint: 0.1,0.1
                    pos_hint: {"left":1, "top":0}
                    color: 0,0,0,1

                Label:
                    text: "testing2"
                    text_size: self.size
                    size_hint: 0.1,0.1
                    pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":0}
                    color: 0,0,0,1
           #writing a message
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1,0.1
                orientation: 'horizontal'

                Button:
                    text: "send"
                    size_hint: 0.1,1
                    on_press: MainScreen.send_message(type.text)

                TextInput:
                    id: type
                    size_hint: 0.9,1
                    hint_text: "type here..."
```

Comment: this is very helpful though is it possible to make the text start from the top and move downwards ? also how can I change the label color inside of the dictionary? I tried: self.ids.messages.data.append({'text': "me: "+message, 'halign': 'left','color':'1,0,1'}) and it doesn't work...

Comment: @NoaBitan the `color` argument takes the form `[r,g,b,a]`, try `'color': [1,0,1,1]` instead of `'color':'1,0,1'`